# Saving, Storing, Loading Photographs in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Good morning everyone!

I've been having some issues regarding photos in my Windows Phone app. I'm trying to take a photo and save it to a record, and then load it up again at a different point.

My idea is to take the photo using the code in this tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006(v=vs.105).aspx)

In my constructor:

```
cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
```

lower down..

```
void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
        //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        //bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.OriginalFileName);
        //string imageLoc = e.OriginalFileName;
        //Uri imageUri = new Uri(imageLoc, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        //StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(imageUri);

        //Code I'm using just now which just displays the photograph
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp2 = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp2.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        myImage.Source = bmp2;
    }
}
```

From my code, you can see that the commented out bit returns the location of the image which has just been taken, then attempts to load it up from there. However, when I try that, I get URI path exceptions and the like. What is going wrong here and what method should I use to remedy it?

I'd like to be able to add the file path to a record and then be able to load it back up elsewhere in my app.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "URI path exceptions and the like". What exception do you get? What is the path?

Comment: I get the exception "A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException" on the line - StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(imageUri); The file path is of the form C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\WP_20140221_003.jpg

Comment: Try just using a FileStream for the given file